# Page expires on every browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a form, when once I have submitted goes to a thank you page. When clicking on a link to a new page and then going back to the thank you page (by pressing back) the page then displays a page expires. This happens on all browsers. How can I make it show the thank you page ?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Put a check on Page_Load on Form Page, and set a cookie/session/DB check, anything you like. Put a condition that if form is already submitted then redirect to thank you page

Stop Back button, this supports on some browsers.
You can clear out history from back button and it will be good to go.
Also you can add this in your Form page

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            javascript:window.history.forward(1);
    </script>
```

Comment: any extra help on how I can set up say a cookie with the form submitted condition

Comment: When you submit form, create a cookie and on Form page at Page_Load check Cookie. check this url
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287533(v=vs.71).aspx